# Hide Admob bannerview on other view

Tags: ios, hide, admob

I use Admob in my app. After an in-app purchase I will remove those banners from every view.

Cause it is a subview, I can't use:

```
<classname>._bannerView.hide;
```

or something like that.
How can I hide the banners from other views?

Thanks!

Comment: Your question is really unclear. Could you rephrase it? .. Also what have you tried so far, where is it going wrong?

Comment: That's not normal syntax. To hide a view: `[viewInstance setHidden:YES];` or `viewInstance.hidden = YES;`. If you want to completely remove the banner view do this instead `[viewInstance removeFromSuperview];`. You can't hide banners from other views, each instance has to be hidden or removed.

Comment: When the In-App Purchase is succeed; I make a NSUserDefaults value.
But the -(void)ViewDidAppear with NSUserDefaults check don't work.

Comment: Can you post the code that doesn't work?

Comment: I don't have any code cause all what I write gives errors before build

Comment: Your contradicting yourself. You say you don't have code, because everything your build gives errors.. which implies you do have code. Please post your code that is giving you an error, and is related to this question, if it is a lot please use an external paste bin.